# how to setup the mailman gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mailman-gem

I'm trying the following guide on mailman

http://dansowter.com/mailman-guide/

up until the `incoming_mail.rb` part I was finding it really easy. But where do I put that file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best place to me, is in the lib directory `lib/incoming_mail.rb`

Comment: ok, it's in the `lib/` directory but I still get this `uninitialized constant IncomingMail (NameError)`

Comment: you need require it `require 'incoming_mail'` or define lib autoload in your application configuration

Comment: i'm almost on the right track here, ``require': no such file to load -- incoming_mail (LoadError)` thanks for the help.

Comment: ok, you try require 'incoming_mail' in your mailman_server.rb script I suppose. If it's that you require after environment in line 9 of mailman_server.rb